# Integration between Zend Framework and Facebook Connect

Tags: php, zend-framework, facebook

I'm developing a web app with zend framework and i'd like to discuss what is the best way to intergrate all the JS and FBML in a ZF project, anyone have some experience.
For example, which may be a good solution for have the Facebook istante in every controllers, a front controller plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since JS and FBML is part of the presentation layer, these would have to go into ViewHelpers. Fetching data from FB via their APIs would go into a service, like Zend_Service_Facebook. There is a proposal for both components in Ready for Review state for some time now:

- http://framework.zend.com/wiki/display/ZFPROP/Zend_Service_Facebook+-+Ian+Warner
- http://code.google.com/p/zend-service-facebook/

Comment: Oh man, Zend_Service_Facebook on GoogleCode is sooo started :D (=empty repository)

Comment: @tomas not my fault and also doesn't make the answer less valid in my opinion. The OP asked about architecture, not ready to use code. If you want ready to use code use http://pear.php.net/package/Services_Facebook

Answer (score 2):

For all those still landing on this POST: There is a Facebook [PHP SDK on github](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/), offered by facebook now.
It is quite helpfull and has a good [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/wiki/_pages) and [examples](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/tree/master/examples).
The other Projects listed above are mostly stopped or in alpha status.

Comment: When I asked this question the facebook SDK already existed. My question was specific about Zend Framework and facebook stuff

Comment: @Luca Bernardi: You can just put the mentioned SDK in you Zend Library Folder and use it pretty much like if it was a Zend Component actually if you do what Gordon wrote as well.
Using it will still save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Zend Framework Library that you can use to access all Facebook Methods at GitHub from your controllers and Models.

https://github.com/erickthered/Facebook-PHP-SDK-for-Zend-Framework

For the views, it's better to add the facebook JS file with the APPID and XFBML parameters to your layout/template so that you can use  tags anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using zend framework 2 you can use this tutorial...

http://kdecom.blogspot.co.nz/2012/10/how-to-login-using-facebook-in-zend.html