# Best practice zend framework + faceBook Api

Tags: php, zend-framework

What is better way to integrate facebook api, in zend framework,
for login I can implement Zend_Auth_Adapter_Interface 
but I found something like Zend_Service_Twitter, and thinking if I should implement Zend_Service_interface  and what are the odds, sorry haven't looked at the architecture of Zend_Service yet, but any advice would be appreciated and would save me time from going to wrong direction

Comment: *Related* http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355773

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While a proposal for a Zend_Service_Facebook exists, the developer didn't release anything to the public yet. You can have a look at http://pear.php.net/package/Services_Facebook and especially Services_Facebook_Auth from this package though.

Also see this blog post:

- http://blog.madarco.net/91/build-a-facebook-application-with-zend-framework/